# You cannot insert the value NULL into the column 'sdept', the table 'XSGL.dbo.student'; the column does not allow Null values. INSERT failed

Tags: sql-server, management-studio-express

There are my problems on SQL Server.
I have a Database named `XSGL` to management the students' information.

First, I create a view named `IS_Student` on **table student**.

[image]

```
CREATE VIEW IS_Student
AS SELECT sno, sname, ssex, sage
FROM student
WHERE sdept = 'IS'
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Then I want to insert a student by the view.

```
INSERT INTO IS_Student 
VALUES('200215129', '赵新', '男', 20) ;
```

But it has an error :

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
不能将值 NULL 插入列 'sdept'，表 'XSGL.dbo.student'；列不允许有 Null 值。INSERT 失败。
语句已终止。
```

I translate it to english.

```
You cannot insert the value NULL into the column 'sdept', the table 'XSGL.dbo.student'; the column does not allow Null values. INSERT failed.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The view `IS_Student` was created on students whose `sdept` is `'IS'`, and I also create it with `WITH CHECK OPTION` . Why does the error tell that I can't  insert the value NULL into the column 'sdept'.

Sorry for my poor Endlish. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

sdebt is not part of your view and it is a not nullable column in your underlying table.
As it's not part of your view, or your INSERT statement, it will try to insert NULL into it - which will make it fail.

Comment: I know I only have 4 values, but the view `IS_Student` was  created on students whose `sdept` is `'IS'`. So when I insert 4 values, it should be transformed to 5 values. The fifth value `IS` was automatically added.

Comment: I edited my answer. What do you mean by "was automatically added", nothing in your provided code will automatically add a value to the non-nullable sdept column.

Comment: `@Cedersved` Why does `sdept` is not part of my view. I donn't understand.

Comment: It isnt exposed on your `VIEW` as it isn't on the `SELECT`, @guapi . As a result an `INSERT` against the `VIEW` will instead thr default value, or `NULL` when there isn't one. Why are you inserting against the `VIEW` anyway and not the table?

Comment: If you for some reason need to do it against the view. You can potentially add a default constraint on the sdebt column, to provide a defined value in case of inserts providing NULL.

Comment: @Cedersved . I'm doing my homework. My textbook shows that the command:
`INSERT INTO IS_Student VALUES('200215129', '赵新', '男', 20) ;`
This command can be transformed to :
`INSERT INTO student(sno, sname, ssex, sage, sdept) VALUES('200215129', '赵新', '男', 20, 'IS') ;`

Answer (score 1):

The condition is part of the view, but the `insert` is executed on the underlying table.

You need to create an Insert Trigger on the view which handles the default value for the view condition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Ins_IS_Student 
ON dbo.IS_Student
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Student (sno, sname, ssex, sage, sdept)
    SELECT sno, sname, ssex, sage, 'IS'
    FROM inserted
END
```

Comment: This command can't be executed. There is an error: `Message 2112, level 16, state 1, procedure TR_Ins_IS_Student, line 1 [batch start line 0]
Because the view "dbo.IS_Student" is defined using CHECK OPTION, the trigger "TR_Ins_IS_Student" cannot be created for this view.`

Comment: I guess you don't need the `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause, because the `WHERE` condition refers to a column which is not `SELECT`ed